# Why does creating a list from a list make it larger?

Tags: python, list, python-internals

I'm seeing some inconsistencies when using `sys.getsizeof` on what should be identical lists. (Python 2.7.5)

```
>>> lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> sys.getsizeof(lst)
76
>>> lst2 = list(lst)
>>> sys.getsizeof(lst2)
104
>>> lst3 = list(lst2)
>>> sys.getsizeof(lst3)
104
>>> sys.getsizeof(lst[:])
76
>>> sys.getsizeof(lst2[:])
76
```

Does anybody have a simple explanation?

Comment: I have a guess, backed by no evidence whatsoever: lists allocate extra memory ahead of time, so that future `append` operations have amortized O(1) complexity. Maybe the difference in sizes is because of different amounts of extra allocated memory.

Comment: @Kevin, you are probably correct as  using `lst2 = lst[:]` returns the same size

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With a list literal, the VM creates the list with a set length. When passing a sequence to the `list()` constructor the elements are added one by one (via [`list.extend()`](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.2/file/10298f4f42dc/Objects/listobject.c#l781)) and as such the list is resized when appropriate. Since the [resize operation](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.2/file/10298f4f42dc/Objects/listobject.c#l25) overallocates in order to amortize the cost, the final list will usually be larger than the source list.

Comment: can you please explain the following a bit more ? *Since the resize operation overallocates in order to amortize the cost, the final list will usually be larger than the source list* thanks !

Comment: @Kasra: If you add 3 spaces but only fill 1 of them then the destination will have 2 more spaces than the source.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so what about if we want to fill 4 space ? i mean how python do this risky task ?

Comment: @Kasra: Once the fourth space needs to be filled, 4 additional spaces would allocated (hypothetically speaking) resulting in 4/7 usage.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ahan ... thansk for replay , i nedd more search about this !

Answer (score 11):

When you create a list literal, the size reported is the minimum size needed to hold the data.  You can see this because the size jumps up if you append a single element.  However, when you use `list` to copy it, it allocates some extra space - it takes a few appends before it reallocates (in your case, I suspect the 8th append will do it - it needs 4 more bytes per element).  There is probably a reason why these allocation behaviors are different, but I'm not sure what that might be.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `append` to gain an insight into the internal structure, it was very helpful.