# Python list memory reallocation issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

If I am using C-Python or jython (in Python 2.7), and for `list` (`[]`) data structure, if I continue to add new elements, will there be memory reallocation issue like how Java ArrayList have (since Java ArrayList requires continuous memory space, if current pre-allocated space is full, it needs re-allocate new larger continuous large memory space, and move existing elements to the new allocated space)?

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29

regards,
Lin

Comment: Cpython lists are implemented as array lists, but append is amortized constant time. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented).

Comment: If you can read C you should take a look at the CPython source code [listobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). The  struct member that holds the pointers to the Python list items is `ob_item`. When the list grows `ob_item` can get reallocated, and the old items are copied, but that's happening at the C level so it's fast. But of course the memory location of the Python list object itself doesn't get affected by that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, confused what means `amortized ` here after reading, could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: @PM2Ring, it seems if extend is not possible dues to cannot find a continuous memory block, then a heavy operation for reallocation is performed -- i.e. moving to a new location takes `O(n)` time (`n` is the number of elements in the list)?

Comment: As I said earlier any copying required happens at the C level so it's much faster than a Python `for` loop. Bear in mind that modern CPUs have efficient opcodes for copying arrays.

Comment: @PM2Ring, understand, I just want to verify reallocation and moving all elements happens, as I experience such issue when I processing large amount of data (1-2G) loading into a list.

Answer (score 2):

The basic story, at least for the main Python, is that a list contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  The list is created with a certain free space (eg. for 8 pointers).  When that fills up, it allocates more memory, and so on.  Whether it moves the pointers from one block of memory to another, is a detail that most users ignore. In practice we just append/extend a list as needed and don't worry about memory use.

[Why does creating a list from a list make it larger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554464/why-does-creating-a-list-from-a-list-make-it-larger)

I assume `jython` uses the same approach, but you'd have to dig into its code to see how that translates to Java.

I mostly answer `numpy` questions.  This is a numerical package that creates fixed sized multidimensional arrays.  If a user needs to build such an array incrementally, we often recommend that they start with a list and append values.  At the end they create the array.  Appending to a list is much cheaper than rebuilding an array multiple times.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, it seems if extend is not possible dues to cannot find a continuous memory block, then a heavy operation for reallocation is performed -- i.e. moving to a new location takes `O(n)` time (`n` is the number of elements in the list)? You can read reply from shanmuga. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: But is the `O(n)` move significant in the broad context?  The interpreter is continually creating and destroying lists and dictionaries in the background.  So the sporadic call to `realloc` to perform this low level move on your list is probably not a speed bottleneck.

Comment: What size lists do you have in mind?   A few hundred numbers?  Nested lists that represent matrices 1000x1000?  Iteration over a list is likely to be more expensive than appending new elements.

Comment: hpaulj, thanks for the advice. I read some other blogs and discussions, sometimes I see even if there is memory reallocation happens, the amortized performance (when considering reallocation cost) is O(1). Any thoughts what means amortized performance?

Answer (score 1):

Internally python lists are Array of pointers as mentioned by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

The next question then is how can you extend the an Array in C as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748052). Which explains this can be done using `realloc` function in C.

This lead me to look in to the behavior of [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) which mentions

> The function may move the memory block to a new location (whose address is returned by the function).

From this my understanding is the array object is **extended if contiguous memory is available, else memory block (containing the Array object not List object) is copied to newly allocated memory block with greater size.**

This is my understanding, corrections are welcome if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks shanmuga, suppose extend is not possible dues to cannot find a continuous memory block, and moving to a new location takes `O(n)` time (`n` is the number of elements in the list)?